# Teamcity Dependencies Password Variable

Tags: passwords, dependencies, teamcity

Can't pass password to the child build in Teamcity.

In the Teamcity project, there is a build that works fine. A password is requested and system login is used.

```
LOGIN       %teamcity.build.triggeredBy.username%
PASSWORD    %secure:teamcity.password.PASSWORD%
```

I create another build and I specify the first build as the child. Teamcity runs a child build with default parameters.

1. To send parameters to the child build, I create the following parameters in the parent:

   reverse.dev.Buil_ID.PARAMETER

With all the usual parameters, this works fine, but the password is not transmitted. If the type of the password field is changed to Text - the password starts to be transmitted, but appears in the logs and parameters in the clear.

2. The variable PASSWORD as %secure:teamcity.password.PASSWORD% is moved to the project level. In the parent build, it is queried and works fine, the variable is not defined in the child build.
3. Define the password as %teamcity.auth.password% In this case, the hash password is passed. How to return it to its original form from hash?

Maybe there are other solutions to the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It's security restrict of Teamcity.
There is two refers in the [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Predefined+Build+Parameters) about password type fields.

> When using build parameters of type "Password", referencing them from a dependency such as %dep..password_parameter% will not retrieve the actual value. This is done for security reasons to prevent dependencies from accessing the value, thus restricting the possibility of unauthorized access to it.
>
> Properties marked by the VCS support as secure (for example, passwords) are not available as reference properties.

Accordinly, `reverse.dep.` also won't work.